# AKS: Long delay to all web request (Waitiing TTFB has large value)

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I am using AKS to deploy my Tomcat-based Java web application.
My cluster is using Kubernetes 1.19.11.
I install Ingress according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-internal-ip guide.

I am using ClusterIP as service which is exposed through ingress. Infront of ingress I am using Application Gateway for public access.

I noticed every web request suffering from long delay as Waiting TTFB.

I tried with turning on --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local in Ingress level.

I also tried with change service to NodePort and use externalTrafficPolicy=Local.

I also tried with disabling monitoring the cluster.

Still no luck.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?